# index outputs content that isn't in the .html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a ruby on rails tutorial to build a simple application using database tables and for some reason my home page outputs more than it should. It creates this array that looks like a database query made with prompt and puts it on the page. I'm pretty sure the problem is with my index.html.erb file (if I empty the file and reload the weird content isn't there), but I can't figure out what's going on. [Here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2rfvrrs.jpg)'s a screenshot of what happens.

```
controller code:
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @page_title = 'Add Book'
    @book = Book.new
    @category = Category.new
    @author = Author.new
    @publisher = Publisher.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @book.save

    redirect_to books_path
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :category_id, :author_id, :publisher_id, :isbn, :price, :buy, :format, :excerpt, :pages, :year, :coverpath)
    end
end
```

html:

```
<div id= "books-index">
    <% @books.each_slice(4) do |book| %>
        <div class = "row">
            <%= book.each do |book| %>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <h3><%= book.title %></h3>
                    <%= image_tag(book.coverpath) %>
                    <%= link_to 'Read More', book_path(book), class:'btn btn-primary' %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I am new to ruby and ruby on rails, so if I need to post any more resources or info in order to make my question clearer please let me know. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put `book.each` call inside of `<%` tag, instead of `<%=` tag:

```
<% books.each do |book| %>
```

Now, you print the result of `books.each` (which is `books` array) into your HTML.

Comment: ugh, and here I was setting up a git repository =) Solved, thanks for the help, will accept once I can

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= book.each do |book| %>
```

The equal after the opening syntax prints the command(s) that follow. That should be the case, try removing it

Comment: thanks, I'll accept Marek Lipka's anwser, since he posted a minute before you

Answer (score 0):

remove`=` from the line `<%= book.each do |book| %>`